# Selenium WebDriverIE Sending single character as Lowecase

Tags: string, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I have recently changed from Windows 7 to a Windows 10 machine and, when running a previous Cucumber unit test pack that was working fine, I am now experiencing issues with `SendKeys` - which is causing all tests to fail unexpectedly. `SendKeys` seems to be sending the first character of a string as a `ToLower()`.

Example:

```
string User = "ANALYSTUSER"
```

I am sending keys as:

```
SendKeys(User) / SendKeys(User.ToUpper())
```

and it is always populating the field as `aNALYSTUSER`!

I have rolled back the `NuGet` Package/driver version through the latest 10 versions and the issue still occurs. (I have also tried the 64-bit driver.)

1. Selenium.Support
2. Selenium.WebDriver
3. Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver

Does anybody have an idea as to what may cause this and what can be tried here?

Comment: Just for fun... have you tried, `string UserUpper = User.ToUpper();` and see if it's working correctly and not just SendKeys? If you paste "ANALYSTUSER" into the field, does it work? I'm just wondering if field validation on that element is going bad.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue relates to your website client side JavaScript, it will change the entered value, I have created a sample using the following code, it works well on my side. You could have a try:

```
    private const string URL = @"https://www.bing.com/";
    private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"E:\webdriver\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0";  // where the Selenium IE webdriver EXE is.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InternetExplorerOptions opts = new InternetExplorerOptions() { IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true};
        using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, opts))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/");   
            var element = driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q"); 
            element.SendKeys("WEBDRIVER"); 

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Besides, you could also try to execute the script to enter a value, code as below.

```
    private const string URL = @"https://www.bing.com/";
    private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"E:\webdriver\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0";  // where the Selenium IE webdriver EXE is.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InternetExplorerOptions opts = new InternetExplorerOptions() { IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true};
        using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, opts))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/");  

            var element = driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");
            var script = "document.getElementById('sb_form_q').value = 'webdriver';";

            IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            jse.ExecuteScript(script, element);

            //element.SendKeys("webdriver");
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        }
    }
```